# Alternative to Windows System Resource Manager in Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, resource-management

Windows System Resource Manager lets one limit the maximum resources used by a process. This is important as I am running a fleet of Remote Desktop Service Session Host computers, and some users have let process instances get out of hand, consuming up to 9GB per process. I need to limit this.

However, [per the bottom of this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997019.aspx), this feature is deprecated in Windows Server 2012 and does not permit install.

It doesn't help much for a non-Hyper-V-based setup.

Are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: Well that sucks, your link is wrong by the way.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh997019.aspx

Comment: how to fix it?..............